# Different behaviour with sudo and without

Tags: bash, shell

I have simple file opening spotify.

```
#!/bin/sh

spotify 1>/dev/null  2>&2 &
```

OR (the same result)

```
#!/bin/sh

spotify &
```

When I run command `sudo sh test.sh` message in console:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
No protocol specified

(spotify:23946): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:14:26.995: cannot open display: :0
```

And when I run `sh test.sh` spotify opens normally without any error.

Can anyone help me understand why it behaves like this? What's the reason and how I can execute command differently with sudo?

Comment: What do you think `2>&2` does, and why do you think you need to run Spotify as root?

Comment: This is only part of my whole script that doesn't work. The minimal reproducible code. Whole script I need to run as root. I edited question.

Comment: Its a known bug in `ubuntu` Check this thread --> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1751634

Comment: Does exist any work around for that bug? I didn't find anything in that thread.